# How to set conditional key,value pairs in terraform for gcp compute instance labels?

Tags: terraform

I am creating a google_compute_instance through terraform. I am setting the labels block there

```
resource google_compute_instance 
{

labels: {
osname=var.osname

//if it is linuxos i need to set this label like 
 //if !local.windowsos then create confidential-vm key/value:
confidential-vm=var.isConfidentialVM

//if it is not linuxos the above label should not be set , i dont want to assign null
}
}
```

How to do this in terraform?
i have created a locals block

I have tried `${!local.iswindowsos}?"confidential-vm=true":""`

```
locals{    
         instance_labels={
        
        ${!local.iswindowsos}?"confidential-vm=true":"" 
        confidential-vm=local.iswindowsos
        }
    }
```

but getting this errors:

Error: Invalid character
│
│   `on vm_instance.tf line 397, in resource "google_compute_instance" "vm":`
│

```
397:     ${!local.iswindowsos}?"confidential-vm=true":"" 
│ 
│ This character is not used within the language. //`$` 

 397:     ${!local.iswindowsos}?"confidential-vm=true":"" 
│ 
│ Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.
```

Comment: You cannot create interdependent configuration in Terraform. In other words, you cannot use value of one argument when deciding should another argument be created. You could create local variables and perform the conditional logic on them. Or you could just set the `confidential_vm` to be equal to `false` when the OS is not Linux.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, i have rephrased my question as I have missed the local block, sorry for that

Comment: Where exactly did you add that code?

Comment: in the locals block, which i will append to the resources block later

Comment: Ok, so the best you can do is probably what is in my answer. You cannot add/remove variables/arguments based on the value of another variable/argument. But maybe someone else will have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try assigning a value to a label when the OS is not Linux, e.g.:

```
locals {
  iswindowsos     = var.windowsos
  confidential_vm = local.iswindows ? true : false

}

resource "google_compute_instance" "instance_name" {
...

 labels {
    osname          = var.osname
    iswindowsos     = local.iswindowsos
    confidential_vm = try(local.confidential_vm, null)
  }
}
```

Comment: i have rephrased my question and added the local block

Comment: So the `confidential_vm` should be created when OS is or is not Windows?

Comment: when it not windows this attribute must be created